# Getting error: "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]" How do I fix?

Tags: c++

I am making a program that converts an English sentence into pig latin. I keep getting the error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]" on line 16. any help?

```
void wordfinder();
string word;
string engSent;
int x;
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    getline(cin, engSent);
    string word = "";
    for (x = 0; x < engSent.length(); x++)
    {
        if (engSent[x] == " " || engSent[x] == "," || engSent[x] == ".")
        {
            wordfinder();
            word = "";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void wordfinder()
{
    word = engSent.substr(0,engSent[x]);
    cout << word;
}
```

Comment: " " is a string. You want ' ' which is a character.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is the comment section. Answers go in the answer section, which you may find down there: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 3):

examine for characters not strings in:

```
if (engSent[x] == ' ' || engSent[x] == ',' || engSent[x] == '.')
```